# How do I select last child node of preceding sibling element with XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath

The XML doc I'm working with has the following structure:

```
<tok id="w-2279">del
  <dtok form="de" id="d-2279-1" ord="20" lemma="de" xpos="SPC00"/>
  <dtok form="el" id="d-2279-2" ord="21" lemma="el" xpos="DA0MS0"/>
</tok> 
<tok id="w-2280" ord="22" lemma="sobredit" xpos="AQ0MS00">sobredit
</tok>
<tok id="w-2281" ord="23" lemma="," xpos="Fc">,
</tok>
```

I need to select the value of attribute 'lemma' in any last child of a 'tok' element that precedes a 'tok' element that has value starting with 'AQ' for the attribute 'xpos'.

I have tried with:

```
//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "AQ")]/preceding::tok/dtok[position()=1]
```

```
//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "AQ")]/preceding::tok/dtok[position()=last()]
```

```
//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "AQ")]/preceding::tok/dtok[1]
```

but the selected 'dtok' element is always the first child (i.e. the one with value 'de' for attribute 'lemma'.

What am I doing wrong? How does one specify that only the last one of all the children must be selected for value extraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your intent with `//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "AQ")]/preceding::tok/dtok[position()=last()]` can be shortened to `//tok[starts-with(@xpos, "AQ")]/preceding::tok/dtok[last()]` and then should work fine and indeed does for me [at the fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=%2F%2Ftok%5Bstarts-with%28%40xpos%2C%20%22AQ%22%29%5D%2Fpreceding%3A%3Atok%2Fdtok%5Blast%28%29%5D&input=%3Croot%3E%0A%3Ctok%20id%3D%22w-2279%22%3Edel%0A%20%20%3Cdtok%20form%3D%22de%22%20id%3D%22d-2279-1%22%20ord%3D%2220%22%20lemma%3D%22de%22%20xpos%3D%22SPC00%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdtok%20form%3D%22el%22%20id%3D%22d-2279-2%22%20ord%3D%2221%22%20lemma%3D%22el%22%20xpos%3D%22DA0MS0%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Ftok%3E%20%0A%3Ctok%20id%3D%22w-2280%22%20ord%3D%2222%22%20lemma%3D%22sobredit%22%20xpos%3D%22AQ0MS00%22%3Esobredit%0A%3C%2Ftok%3E%0A%3Ctok%20id%3D%22w-2281%22%20ord%3D%2223%22%20lemma%3D%22%2C%22%20xpos%3D%22Fc%22%3E%2C%0A%3C%2Ftok%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: Thank you very much once again, Martin.I was testing it on a different online XPATH tester (http://xpather.com) and I had not enclosed the excerpt of my doc within <root>. In your 'fiddle' tester (thank you, by the way, very useful resource), it doesn't evaluate and so you know there is a problem. When I dit it with 'xpather', it kept on highlighting the first node and I was going crazy because it didn't make sense. If you enclose everything within <root>, it works as expected both in the long and shortened versions.